# JavaScript - How to change a dom node back to an existing Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom

I set a div to a class which shows a spinning animated when the map is loading some data, the question is, how can I set the div back to the map (I don't want to load a new map, but load the existing one, which is assigned to a var 'map')?

```
//map is assigned originally like this:
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map3'),options);

//animated graphic is assigned to map div on load of data:
document.getElementById('map3').className = "loading";
```

but how to get the map back?

Thanks for any tips!

David

Comment: What do you mean with "get the map back"? Do you need the javascript object or the visual representation of the map?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to redisplay the map object in the div map3.

Comment: I don't get the problem can you please post more code (html, css, js) or add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a event listener to the google map object and after it is loaded you can remove your loading-class.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('map3').className = "";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am not looking for a way to attach an event to detect anything, just a way to redisplay the map.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you.   I had previously tried to assign the classname to blank but this had not helped (I think because the node contains text in the form of a message as well ass the classname. Probably I've not made this problem for anyone reading this to understand so I'll have a bit more of a look and get back to you.